# Doing clean-up inside finally block, with return in try block - bad practice?

Tags: javascript, try-finally

I have this code to figure out the width of some text:

```
function textWidth(text, font) {
    const span = document.createElement('span')
    try {
        span.style.cssText = `position: absolute; opacity: 0; font: ${font || "'Arial'"};`
        span.innerText = text
        document.body.appendChild(span)

        return span.offsetWidth
    } finally {
        document.body.removeChild(span)
    }
}
```

Is it bad practice to do the clean-up inside finally when the try block is returning something? It works as expected; this question is not about how `try...finally` works, I get that part. I'm just wondering if it would for some reason be better to store the width in a variable, do the clean-up, and then return the variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it bad practice to do the clean-up inside finally when the try block is returning something?

No, it's perfectly normal practice.

When you do `return span.offsetWidth`, the value of `span.offsetWidth` is evaluated and put to one side, then the `finally` code is run, and then that value is returned. No need to do that manually. Your `finally` could even have `span = null;` in it, and it wouldn't affect your return value because the expression `span.offsetWidth` has *already* been evaluated at that point.

You can see that in [the spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-return-statement-runtime-semantics-evaluation):

> **Runtime Semantics: Evaluation**
>
> *ReturnStatement*: `return` *Expression*;
>
> 1. Let *exprRef* be the result of evaluating *Expression*.
> 2. Let *exprValue* be ? GetValue(*exprRef*).
> 3. If ! GetGeneratorKind() is async, set *exprValue* to ? Await(*exprValue*).
> 4. Return Completion { [[Type]]: return, [[Value]]: *exprValue*, [[Target]]: empty }.

In that excerpt, the value is in `exprValue`, which becomes part of the completion record (that's a spec mechanism, not necessarily a real thing); then the `finally` code is run, and the function completes with that completion record (unless of course, `finally` throws or issues a different `return` that supercedes this `return`).

And you can also observe it:

```js
function example() {
  let foo = () => {
    console.log("foo called");
    return 42;
  };
  try {
    console.log("Doing: return foo();");
    return foo();
  } finally {
    console.log("finally block, doing foo = null");
    foo = null;
  }
}
console.log(example());
```